# Htaccess - Rewrite Rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**What I have:**

My Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!user?)([a-z0-9.-]+)+(\/)?$ index.php?page=$1
```

**What I want**

So if I go to `http://localhost/hello/`, I want to get `hello` in the `$1`

But if I go to `http://localhost/user/` I want to do nothing in this RewriteRule :) Because other RewriteRule is handling the special pages :)

**What's the problem:**

Instead getting `hello` as `$1` , I get `index.php`, why and how should I fix this?

I also tested the regex with `preg_replace` here: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ and works :\

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
RewriteRule ^user/?$ user.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```